How to optimize the code of tesseract OCR to increase the accuracy of the data extraction?
I have this image-based pdf file. I converted this pdf file into the jpg image.
Ledger Image
Now I want to extract the data from this image using Tesseract OCR. I have written this code now please tell me some modififcations to increase the accuracy of the extraction.
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
from pytesseract import Output
from tabulate import tabulate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import imutils
import cv2

# Define input image path and output CSV path directly
input_image_path = "Final OCR Code/ledger KANAK[1]_page-0001.jpg"  # Replace with your image path
output_csv_path = "Final OCR Code/results11.csv"  # Replace with your desired output path

# Set other parameters
min_conf = 0
dist_thresh = 25.0
min_size = 2

# set a seed for our random number generator
np.random.seed(42)

# load the input image and convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread(input_image_path)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# initialize a rectangular kernel that is ~5x wider than it is tall,
# then smooth the image using a 3x3 Gaussian blur and then apply a
# blackhat morphological operator to find dark regions on a light
# background
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (51,11))
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
blackhat = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, kernel)

# Display the Gaussian Blurred image
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
plt.title('Gaussian Blurred Image')
plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

# Display the Blackhat image
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
plt.title('Blackhat Image')
plt.imshow(blackhat, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

# compute the Scharr gradient of the blackhat image and scale the
# result into the range [0, 255]
grad = cv2.Sobel(blackhat, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=-1)
grad = np.absolute(grad)
(minVal, maxVal) = (np.min(grad), np.max(grad))
grad = (grad - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal)
grad = (grad * 255).astype("uint8")

# Display the Scharr Gradient image
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
plt.title('Scharr Gradient Image')
plt.imshow(grad, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

# apply a closing operation using the rectangular kernel to close
# gaps in between characters, apply Otsu's thresholding method, and
# finally a dilation operation to enlarge foreground regions
grad = cv2.morphologyEx(grad, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
thresh = cv2.threshold(grad, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)

# Display the final thresholded image
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
plt.title('Final Thresholded Image')
plt.imshow(thresh, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

# find contours in the thresholded image and grab the largest one,
# which we will assume is the stats table
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
tableCnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# compute the bounding box coordinates of the stats table and extract
# the table from the input image
# Extract the bounding box of the table and extract the table itself
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(tableCnt)
table = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]

# Display the original input image
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
plt.title('Original Input Image')
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

# Display the extracted table image
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
plt.title('Extracted Table Image')
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(table, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

# set the PSM mode to detect sparse text, and then localize text in
# the table
options = "--psm 11"  # Or try using --psm 11
results = pytesseract.image_to_data(cv2.cvtColor(table, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), config=options, output_type=Output.DICT)

# initialize a list to store the (x, y)-coordinates of the detected
# text along with the OCR'd text itself
coords = []
ocrText = []

# loop over each of the individual text localizations
for i in range(0, len(results["text"])):
    # extract the bounding box coordinates of the text region from
    # the current result
    x = results["left"][i]
    y = results["top"][i]
    w = results["width"][i]
    h = results["height"][i]
    # extract the OCR text itself along with the confidence of the
    # text localization
    text = results["text"][i]
    conf = int(results["conf"][i])

    # filter out weak confidence text localizations
    if conf > min_conf:
        # update our text bounding box coordinates and OCR'd text
        # respectively
        coords.append((x, y, w, h))
        ocrText.append(text)

# extract all x-coordinates from the text bounding boxes, setting the
# y-coordinate value to zero
xCoords = [(c[0], 0) for c in coords]

# apply hierarchical agglomerative clustering to the coordinates
# apply hierarchical agglomerative clustering to the coordinates
clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(
    n_clusters=None,
    metric="manhattan",  
    linkage="complete",
    distance_threshold=dist_thresh
)
clustering.fit(xCoords)

# initialize our list of sorted clusters
sortedClusters = []

# loop over all clusters
for l in np.unique(clustering.labels_):
    # extract the indexes for the coordinates belonging to the
    # current cluster
    idxs = np.where(clustering.labels_ == l)[0]

    # verify that the cluster is sufficiently large
    if len(idxs) > min_size:
        # compute the average x-coordinate value of the cluster and
        # update our clusters list with the current label and the
        # average x-coordinate
        avg = np.average([coords[i][0] for i in idxs])
        sortedClusters.append((l, avg))

# sort the clusters by their average x-coordinate and initialize our
# data frame
sortedClusters.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
df = pd.DataFrame()

# loop over the clusters again, this time in sorted order
for (l, _) in sortedClusters:
    # extract the indexes for the coordinates belonging to the
    # current cluster
    idxs = np.where(clustering.labels_ == l)[0]
    # extract the y-coordinates from the elements in the current
    # cluster, then sort them from top-to-bottom
    yCoords = [coords[i][1] for i in idxs]
    sortedIdxs = idxs[np.argsort(yCoords)]

    # generate a random color for the cluster
    color = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(3,), dtype="int")
    color = [int(c) for c in color]

    # loop over the sorted indexes
    for i in sortedIdxs:
        # extract the text bounding box coordinates and draw the
        # bounding box surrounding the current element
        (x, y, w, h) = coords[i]
        cv2.rectangle(table, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)

    # extract the OCR'd text for the current column, then construct
    # a data frame for the data where the first entry in our column
    # serves as the header
    cols = [ocrText[i].strip() for i in sortedIdxs]
    currentDF = pd.DataFrame({cols[0]: cols[1:]})

    # concatenate *original* data frame with the *current* data
    # frame (we do this to handle columns that may have a varying
    # number of rows)
    df = pd.concat([df, currentDF], axis=1)

# Replace NaN values with an empty string and then show a nicely
# formatted version of your multi-column OCR'd text
df.fillna("", inplace=True)
print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql"))

# Write the table to disk as a CSV file
print("[INFO] saving CSV file to disk...")
df.to_csv(output_csv_path, index=False)

# Show the output image after performing multi-column OCR using matplotlib
plt.figure(figsize=(40,40))
plt.title('Output Image')
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()


Please modify the code however you like just help me to get all the data extracted in csv file for with highest accuracy possible.
This is the image from which I am trying to extract the data from.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
